# designing a distributed (over many servers) error logging feature, WCF or?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, error-logging

I am designing a error logging feature so our servers (each donig different things) can have a central data store for logging errors.

Would it be a good idea to have the various applications writing to the error log file using a WCF service, or is that a bad idea?

they *can* do it just by ADO.NET to the database, which I think is the simpler route.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say just log to your local data store.  The advantages are :

1. Speed - it's pretty rapid to just
   dump your chosen error report to an
   existing data connection.
2. Tracability - What happens if you
   have an error in your service?  You
   lose all ability to chase down
   errors on all servers.
3. Simplicity - If you change the
   endpoint for your errors service,
   you have to update every other
   application that uses the error
   service.
4. Reporting - Do you really want to
   trawl through error reports from
   tens / hundreds of applications in
   one place when you could easily find
   them in the data store local to the
   app?

Of course, any of these points could be viewed from the other side, these are just my opinions.

Comment: there will be maybe 10-20 different apps/services I think, but yeah point taken.

Answer (score 1):

How about having a look at syslog? It was made for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

We're looking at a similar approach, except for audit logging as well as error handling.

Looking at using WCF over netTcp, also looking at using the event log, but that seems to require high trust settings, and maybe performance issues.

Not convinced by ZombieSheep's objections:

1. It's pretty rapid to dump your chosen error report over an existing WCF connection. Seriously. Plus, you can do it async/queued. Not a key factor for me.
2. You log to the central service and the local service. When the erroer service comes back on line, you poll your machines for events since the last timestamp. Problem solved.
3. Use a dns alias, and don't change the path - the way you should do internal addressing anyway IMO.
4. What if you have multiple apps on a single machine? What if you want to see the timing of errors across multiple apps?